# Which is the correct description - "hydrogens" or "hydrogen atoms"?

Tags: discussion

This has really been troubling me for quite a long time now. I don't have the relevant literature to confirm whether writing "hydrogens" is correct or "hydrogen atoms" is (for the same matter, "oxygens" vs "oxygen atoms", etc.).

According to me, "hydrogen" refers to the element hydrogen. Thus, "hydrogens" refers to *elements of hydrogen* OR *element hydrogens*, which makes no sense to me. In this context, "hydrogen atoms" does indeed make sense, as it refers to *atoms of the element hydrogen*.

Which one of them is the correct description?

---

An interesting statistic: [641 distinct posts](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22hydrogens%22) on Chem.SE mention "hydrogens", vs [515 distinct posts](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22hydrogen+atoms%22) mentioning "hydrogen atoms".

Comment: I really think both are fine and most likely clear from context.

Comment: @Martin-マーチン Yes, me too! :) Though the "hydrogens" does feel weird to me sometimes.

Comment: Every chemistry professor I've encountered, with whom this conversation has arisen, has preferred "hydrogen atoms."

Comment: There may be a split between written and spoken usage. When speaking we often use shortcuts (dropping the 'atoms') that we might not when writing, particularly in formal contexts.

Comment: @Zhe I had one particular professor who strongly rejected "hydrogen atoms" or using "atoms" in general, when talking about a molecule, because they are no longer atoms so h{is..er} argument.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say this is just a case of formal vs. informal speech.  I teach chemistry for a living and I would never *write* "hydrogens" or "carbons" but I can guarantee you that I have *said* "hydgrogens" and "carbons" many times while referring Lewis structures or concepts related to NMR, etc. in class or office hours.  While it may look a little ugly on the written page, it's unambiguous and quickly communicates the intended meaning.